# How to extend NTFS partition onto multiple disks in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I am trying to create as large a partition as possible on my Windows machine. I want to merge two partitions located on two disks into one logical volume. These two disks are contiguous (Disks 0 and 1). There is also a partition on Disk 3 that is unallocated and I would ideally like to include in this massive partition as well, but I don't know if I can because Disk 2 lies in between. I will try to explain the setup of my partitions and disks as best as possible.

I have 4 disks (0, 1, 2, and 3) in total. Disk 2 contains my C: volume which is configured to be the boot, page file, crash, and dump partition. Disk 0 contains a dynamic volume of size 595.93 GB NTFS. On Disk1 is a partition with 588.17 GB of unallocated space. Disk 3 first contains 100 MB of System reserved space, followed by a partition with 596.07 GB of unallocated space.

My primary goal is create a single partition from the dynamic volume on Disk 0 merged with the unallocated space on Disk 1. When I right click the unallocated partition and choose "New Spanned Volume", I am unable to proceed past the second window because the "Next" button is grayed out, despite having selected Disk 1 as the disk I want to use. I then tried right clicking on the dynamic partition on Disk 0, choosing "Extend Volume", and clicking "Next". This then warns me that it will make the disk I'm extending onto (Disk 1) a dynamic disk, which I'm OK with. However it immediately fails with a "There is not enough space on the disk to complete this operation."

Finally, I started up Powershell and ran DISKPART to try to perform these operations via a command line interface. I chose disk 1 with

```
select disk 1
```

I then tried to make it an extended partition by running

```
create partition extended
```

But it returned the error

```
Virtual Disk Service error:
the number of partitions has reached the limit on this disk
```

OK. I have tried to explain my situation as well as I can. Can someone reply with an answer on ways to troubleshoot this problem I am having, either using a terminal or through some GUI service? While I could just make basic unextended volumes out of all the unallocated space, I want to merge them because then I can have a single directory (one that contains large amounts of large files like movies for example) on a single volume.

Comment: You need to be looking into RAID arrays - but you'd need to be able to back up all your data first, as formatting a RAID is destructive. Some elementary info can bee seen at http://www.pcworld.com/article/194360/raid-made-easy.html

Comment: @Tetsujin are you referring to RAID 0 (striping)? I'm starting to think the best method is just to backup everything, wipe everything, and reformat the disks so that the I can make as large a volume as possible.